# Heavenly Host Daycare and Correctional Facility for misbehaving gods: Bahamut and Tiamat 1/2: Containment

Tags: science-based, chemistry, engineering

Once upon a time there was a world called, "The Gone, but not Forgotten Realms", ran by #GamerGate Garry and #ClintonBodyCount Anon. One day, Anon got tired of Garry taking his work for granted and abusing his children. Therefore Anon, the stepfather of all monsters and gods, overthrew Garry and assumed his place as the Game Master.

Unfortunately, Anon's children have rather bad manners, which conflicts with their supposed divine role, and are constantly fighting with each other. For all he crimes he commited against humanity, Anon still has a heart and **doesn't want to hurt them**, but he has to start discipling the gods for their own sake.

Anon no longer has the power (his Requiem ability is close to useless when he's unwilling to rewrite memories) or the will to behave them alone. So, he has to rely on other humans

**Heavenly Host Daycare and Correctional Facility for misbehaving deities** is a place specifically designed by Anon to protect the world from gods and gods from themselves.

Just as the name suggests the facility is suffering from an identity crisis. It can best be summed up as a summer camp that looks like a prison. Residents have team-building programs with Anon and a "recess" where they can go anywhere in the facility except where they aren't allowed. And yes, there is lunch time, and yeees, there ARE foodfights.

Be aware that besides their described abilities, gods are only special because they have escalated priviliges (not important for now) in the system (that are temporarily revoked while in the facility) and resurrective immortality (should they die, they wake up next to the bed in their cells after some time with no trace of the dead body).

---

### Tiamat and Bahamut

The dragon twins, Tiamat and Bahamut, are the psychic commanders of dragonkind. They often quarrel, but rarely at full power.

- As a breath weapon, Tia and Bahamut shoot pellets of octonitrocubane, coated with a biofuel to produce a rather powerful **thermobaric bomb**. They have a shot-limit of five pellets/day.
- They aren't powerful fliers, but are nonetheless capable of up to 90 seconds of powered flight and much more when gliding.
- They aren't physically strong, comparable to the largest members of the Azdarchidae.
- Nor they are big, roughly the size of a Shire horse.
- Both are capable of spitting **hydrochloric acid** at around a litre per day.

**What general adaptations should be made to the facility's structure and furnishment to be able to endure direct hits from the dragons?**

### Rules and principle of design

---

**Be Safe:** Damaged equipment or parts of the building should pose no further danger (example: no asbestos or arsenic in the building material)
 **Be Simple:** Simple stuff is harder to break, generally
 **Be Enduring:** The facility should require minimal maintenance.

*You can get as modern-day with technology as you want.*

Comment: Are there any constraints limiting what can be done? Do they need to be awake and aware the entire time? Do they need exercise time? Do they have free access to this "facility"? Do they get meals in a "cell" or among others? Is there not a "warden" with the divine power to suppress the divine powers of others while they are within the "facility"?

Comment: @Frostfyre Good question, I'll ad the info pls wait...

Comment: "_escalated priviliges_"... like what? what powers do the creators of the camp have? "_and resurrective immortality_" resurrect where? suicide teleportation, anyone?

Answer (score 5):

Given godlike powers, what on earth are you doing mucking about with buildings? Just put them somewhere unbearably dull, where there's nothing to do and nothing to break.

At the limit, this could be something resembling an ocean world with few landmasses and primitive ocean life suitable for providing an inhabitable atmosphere. Hungry? Catch some weird looking proto-fish-shrimp-thing. You can't fly out, because there's nowhere to fly. You can't do any damage if you throw a tantrum, because there's nothing to damage, just the boring rock you're standing on that's sticking out of the boring ocean under a boring sky where, if you are a particularly mean overdeity, there aren't even any boring stars or moons to look at. Just dull, for the next 2 billion years, or until you learn to behave yourself. Whichever comes first.

At a smaller scale, you can replicate this without having actually divine powers by dumping the offenders on a suitable island in the middle of nowhere. Rockall springs to mind, but there are larger places if needs be. Supplies can be sent in by drone. If you shoot down a supply drone, you'll go hungry next time a shipment is due.

---

If you actually wanted a *building* (and if you were, what on earth was all that stuff about gods for?) then how about thinking small? A cell lined with silicon carbide will be acid resistant and quite hard to smash out of. If the cell is small enough, then setting off a thermobaric bomb inside it is likely to be Quite Bad for the bomber. Into solitary confinement with you.

Comment: Sorry for not giving all the detail. The question should now contain all the important info, if it doesn't, tell me in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Tiamat and Bahamut's pellets are actually not very powerful if we enforce the "science-based" tag. Octanitrocubane is a fast explosive (the fastest known actually), but projected brisance isn't all that great - it goes "clack" instead of "booooom". Also, even with a quite large 100 g pellet, you don't actually get a thermobaric explosion at all - for that you need a *slow*, low temperature explosive to disperse the fuel and combine it with atmospheric oxygen at an optimal stechiometric ratio, *before* it detonates. As things stand, the largest part of the detonation would be supplied by the cubane reaction, with the biofuel contributing with a post-detonation flame. Difference in explosion speed means that you have two lesser explosions separated by a few milliseconds.

Given all that, you can build the facility using PTFE-lacquered, spring-mounted interlocked steel tiles. The greatest part of the force of the explosion would simply be reflected back (they're pellets, not anti-armor bullets), and the tiles would absorb the rest; back in the 80's there already was the technology to build shock absorbers capable of withstanding a [nonconfined nuclear explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)). PTFE is resistant to hydrochloric acid.

Comment: I assumed the "biofuel" part of the description provided the thermobaric oomph, though engineering a bursting charge and then an igniting charge then went off shortly afterwards so as to properly create and light the fuel cloud seems awkward.

Comment: Bursting/ignition is how thermobaric devices work. You need to intimately mix the fuel with air, and that is where the bursting charge comes in. The energy is supplied by the fuel detonation, and fuel detonation speed (and specific energy) gives you the brisance (destructive power). TB devices trade lower peak pressures but larger total energy, recognizing that even a moderate overpressure is lethal to humans and most structures.

Answer (score 0):

Your Correctional Facility is Likely Doomed.

Having access to up to modern day technology, and no further? You could make barriers or walls out of any material, and they just won't last very long when subjected to 10 thermobaric bombs and two liters of hydrochloric acid a day.

**My suggestion is to create this facility underwater, because hydrochloric acid is highly soluable in water and because water helps spread the energy from the explosions. Additionally, the dragons may or may not be able to enter the water for long periods of time**